# Motion blur with vector in compositor

Tags: compositing-nodes, motion-blur

I'm trying to follow along [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZiSsykf_JBY) here.

It's a simple tutorial where the instructor ends up adding motion blur on a blue monkey, but without using the "motion blur" in Render properties. Screenshot from the tutorial, result:

[image]

It seems like blender is updated, and "vector" is no longer defined in the "view layer properties" - is the new input called the "normal"? Anyways here is my attempt to get motion blur on a moving cube. It's not working.

[image]

Any ideas?

Edit //
I'm using Blender 3.4.1 can't find the vector option in ViewLayer

[image]

Comment: I'm seeing vector in properties/view layer (in passes/data).  In 3.4.1.  Are you sure you're looking in the right place?  "Normal" is not the same thing.

Comment: Just upgraded to 3.4.1, still not visible

Comment: You are using Eevee then? in Eevee MB is so cheap, you don't need to fake it. Updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This option is not available in EEVEE, try to use Cycles instead.

It seems to be EEVEE Next will have vector pass.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Normal pass as motion vectors. Do this in the View Layer Properties:
[image]

That makes the Vector output (see your 1. screenshot) appear and you can use it with the vector blur node

If you are using Eevee, the option will not be available, because it is very cheap anyways and would actually take longer to apply it in post, just make sure it's enabled:

[image]

Comment: I don't have that option in Linux blender 3.4.1.. Did you do anything in the settings to get this option? (see new image in description of the issue)